# ¿Cómo calcular automáticamente al cambiar el valor de celda en GridView?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015, gridview

Tengo un control de cuadrícula ***GridView*** Devexpress, en el que las filas se cargan desde una base de datos, lo que se requiere es que **cuando marque la casilla, se active el botón Aceptar** y si no hay ninguna fila activa, el botón esté desactivado. Además, cuando **cambia el valor de la celda de precio, el valor de Total cambia automáticamente**. 
La cantidad de celdas activadas se refleja en la etiqueta y en el total de Total (ver imagen).

Intenté hacer con el evento gridView1_CellValueChanged(...) pero no funciona o a veces se activa cuando enfoco o hago clic en otro control o el valor se vuelve cero.

```
 private void gridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int aux = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if ((bool)gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, gridView1.Columns[0]))
            {
                aux++;
            }
        }

        btnOk.Enabled = aux > 0;

        var summaryValue = gridView1.Columns["Total"].SummaryItem.SummaryValue;
        Label1.text = "Total select "+ summaryValue.ToString();
    }
```

[image: GridView]

Comment: Para calcular el `Total` cual es la formula que debes usar? Multiplicar/Sumar el precio por..?? En ninguna parte de tu código veo donde realizas una operación para cambiar la celda Total en el `GridView`

Comment: Este lo realiza todo: **var summaryValue = gridView1.Columns["Total"].SummaryItem.SummaryValue;** el detalle que al cambiar de valor en la celda el total debe actualizarse automaticamente